# Recyclerview single item selection with changing color in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, onitemclick

I have question, I want to make an item clicked in recyclerview, in adapter class I used the below method for define item clicked:

```
var onItemClick: ((ResponseGetDate) -> Unit)? = null
```

*ResponseGetDate is the data class*

also in the viewHolder (inner class) I used above variable for defining item clicked:

```
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClick?.invoke(itemDate)

    }
```

*itemData is an item of ResponseGetDate class*

Now, in the main activity or fragment when I build an instance from the adapter class, I can click on each item. see the code below:

```
      adapterGetDate.onItemClick = { dateItem ->

      }
```

**The question is: if I want to click on each item, the item must be selected. and if I click on the another item, previous item must be deselected and the new one be selected. How can I do this?**

Comment: What does the recycler item look like?

Answer (score 1):

Single item selection can be maintained in RecyclerView by

- Two variables to be kept updated when an item is selected
- The first variable maintains the currently selected position
- The second variable maintains the last selected position
- Two different background drawable for the selected and unselected
  items
- Two methods in ViewHolder Class to change the background of items

**Background drawable**
For the item selected in my example:

Drawable name: bg_capsule_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
     android:radius="300dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <solid android:color="@color/colorOffGreen" />
</shape>
```

For the item unselected

Drawable name: bg_capsule_unselected

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
     android:radius="300dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#11B8B7BA" />
    <solid android:color="#F3F3F4" />
</shape>
```

**Variables**

Two variables to be initialized in your Adapter Class

```
var selectedItemPos = -1
var lastItemSelectedPos = -1
```

Separate methods in the ViewHolder Class for changing the background of the items when selected and unselected

```
fun defaultBg() {
    binding.tvCurrencyName.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_capsule_unselected)
}

fun selectedBg() {
    binding.tvCurrencyName.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_capsule_selected)
}
```

**Logic**
The logic is to update the variables and calling the `notifyItemChange(position)` which would then call the method `onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)` for this to happen we have to initialize the click listener for each of the `itemViews` and update the variables accordingly with the adapter position and call `notifyItemChange()` method with passing the item position to change

```
init {
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        selectedItemPos = adapterPosition
        if(lastItemSelectedPos == -1)
            lastItemSelectedPos = selectedItemPos
        else {
            notifyItemChanged(lastItemSelectedPos)
            lastItemSelectedPos = selectedItemPos
        }
        notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPos)
       onItemClick?.invoke(itemDate) // here you can keep the callback
    }
}
```

this code is written inside the ViewHolder Class as an init block Since we have set click listeners for every `itemView` and then when we call `notifyItemChange()` method would call `onBindViewHolder()` method and in this method, we would check for the position and change their background with the help of two methods written inside ViewHolder Class like this

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if(position == selectedItemPos)
        holder.selectedBg()
    else
        holder.defaultBg()
    holder.bindItems(adapterList[position])
}
```

Comment: Linking to some article is NOT an asnwer. [What is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)